# How to get the Keras history object when you abort training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, abort

When I train with tensorflow 2.0 / Keras APIs, I usually do something like this

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
history = model.fit(x, y, batch_size=64, epochs=10)
```

But sometimes things in life don't work out how I planned and I need to abort with ctrl-c or pressing stop in Jupyter notebook.
How can I still get the history object when I abort training early? I can't find any detailed documentation for how to get history.

Comment: Did you actually try to access it and got an error?

Comment: Yes, the error is `NameError: name 'history' is not defined`

Comment: You can get it as an attribute of the model, i.e. `model.history`.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @today in a [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574871/how-to-get-the-keras-history-object-when-you-abort-training#comment112421719_63574871), the `history` object is also available as an attribute of `model`:

```
model.history.history['val_loss']
```